# SAPUI5 - Remove oData Model bound to view

Tags: sapui5

I am new to SAPUI5 and I am very much in need of your help.

I have created an XML view and bound an OData model to it like below. Now all the controls in the view got bound and I am able to see the data.

```
this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

Now I have a requirement in which I have to completely remove this binding from the view. I destroyed the oModel and removed all its bindings. And now when I refresh the view, the data still exists in the screen. I want all the data from the view to disappear.

```
oModel.destroy();
oModel.refresh();
this.getView().getModel().refresh(true);
```

Comment: one any event such as button Press event try to set all field as empty.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're using an `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel` to retrieve odata, then done binding using, for example, a JSON model, like so,

`var oJson = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({data : oData);`

`/* Here 'data' is any name that you provide to identify your data model,
 'oData' is the data that is received as response from the sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel */`

And set this model to the view like you have mentioned,

`this.getView().setModel();`

Now, to remove this data from the view you can try the following,

`oJson.setData({data : null}, true);`

This would set the previously set `oData` to `null` and therefore all data binding from the controls in the view would be removed(changed to null). 
I believe `oJson.refresh()` is optional, but you can try adding that as well if the change is not reflected.

Its an approach until may be you find something better :) [Here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html) is the documentation for the APIs that I've used.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using

```
var dataModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
dataModel.setData(oDataResponse); //Data returned from oData.Read()
this.getView().setModel(dataModel, "dataModel");
```

Retrieve the model, Set the model to null, Update the binding

```
var dataModel = this.getView().getModel("dataModel"); 
if(dataModel){
    dataModel.setData(null);
    dataModel.updateBindings(true);
}
```